# Ruby Gem with Acroynym in the name

Tags: ruby, rubygems

[SOLVED: See my comment below]

I've created a Ruby Gem to connect to my application's API: my_app_api. I'd like to use it like so: `MyAppAPI::Foo.bar()`. However, I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MyAppAPI
```

I know the standard way to call/name this would be `MyAppApi::Foo.bar()`, but I'd prefer to keep with acronym class naming conventions. How do I specify/load the module?

For reference, the class looks like this:

```
module MyAppAPI

 class Foo < ActiveResource::Base
 extend MyAppAPI

 self.site = 'http://localhost:3000/api/'
 self.format = :json

 class << self

   def bar
     return 'huzzah!'
   end

 end

  end
end
```

And the `my_app_api.rb` file looks like this:

```
require "rubygems"
require 'active_resource'

require 'my_app_api/foo'
```

Comment: Looks like this was actually a result of an RVM problem (I had an older version of the gem installed in the global gemset, and it wasn't getting installed). Thanks for the thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the gem the normal way?

```
require 'my_app_api'
MyAppAPI::Foo.bar()
```

The constant name MyAppAPI is fine and is not the cause of the problem.  There are tons of Ruby core classes/modules that have acronyms in their names:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC.html
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/RubyVM.html
- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: I've updated the question with code examples. The problem definitely has something to do with the constant name, as MyAppApi::Foo.bar() works fine, if I adjust the naming in the class declaration. I'm sure this is something very simple--some place where I'm failing to declare something. I know it's trivial, and works fine elsewhere--I'm just not sure what I need to do differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the empty module in my_app_api.rb after your `require` statements:

```
module MyAppAPI
end
```

This may help if you're relying on a dynamic class and module loading mechanism (like Rails uses).

I assume your app is explicitly calling `require "my_app_api"`. What kind of app is this, and where are you doing the `require`?